# Sql Server 2005 Analysis Service -cannot connect to sql browser

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service, analysis

This is my first attempt at using Business Intelligence development studio.
I have set up the project and now trying to deploy my changes. When I run the project I get an error ensure that sql browser is running.

Done- setting up cubes & mining structure.
Checked that database instance is correct.
I have checked that sql2005 is running.

Can someone give me pointers on how to get around this problem?

Comment: this is what i get when i try to connect to analysis service through management studio
 connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2382 (System)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referred to the following 
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/SQLServerdatamining/Jun2005/post23396286.asp

it worked for me ..thanks for the answers

Comment: Use this reference...for complete setup
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167105%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the server, go to Start-->Control Panel. Then, go to Administrative Tools, and open Services. Scroll down to SQL Server Browser. Right click it, and hit "Start." Voila, the Browser is running!

Answer (score 0):

Is your server configured to allow remote connections, and is your firewall configured to let traffic through to Analysis services and the browser service?